# Embedding videos in pdf for playback on Mac

Tags: pdftex, media9, multimedia

I'm trying to make a pdf with videos for viewing on a Mac. I know how to do this on Linux, but have never tried viewing it on a Mac. 
Is there an easy way to embed the videos (I have them in any format needed), for instance media9, that will work without special players?
I don't have a Mac to test this on, as it is for a presentation at a conference. 
I've looked at the old discussions on the topic of embedding multimedia, but as far as I've found they all concern viewing on Linux.

Comment: On OSX, mp4 video embedded with `media9` can be played back with the latest AdoberReader and FlashPlayer plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to play a video in a pdf on a mac, it is quite easy.

There is a problem unfortunately the native app on a mac (preview.app) it is not capable on playing it. But if they allow you, you can download the adobe reader for mac and it will work.

The way to add the video is the same as you know you just only have to open it with adobe reader.

Hope this helps.

Bye

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't get it to work with `media9` and videos in `.flv` and `.mp4` (h264), running on acrobat reader. But as it wasn't my Mac I don't know if it was set up correctly for flash playback.
Thank you for the help:)

Comment: You don't have to be sorry, I brought my computer with Linux as backup, so I didn't suffer. Thank you again